# Erro em sistema depois que subiu para servidor

Tags: php, codeigniter

O sistema foi desenvolvido em php utilizando o framework codeigniter 3.

Funciona muito bem no localhost.

Subi para o servidor e começou a dar problemas. Verifiquei o php instalado e está na versão 5.6

Erros que acontecem:

> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int
>
> Filename: models/Usuarios_model.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user145/public_html/sistema/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)
>
> Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 564

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usuarios_model extends CI_Model {

public function login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where("username", $username);
    $this->db->where("password", $password);

    $resultados = $this->db->get("usuarios");

    if ($resultados > 0) { ----------------------> LINHA 12
        return $resultados->row();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}}
```

Quando volto em alguma página acontece este erro:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: unlink(/tmp/ci_session9c9ddb88511925d48aa2df5fd44857177296879f):   Operation not permitted
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 384
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: >/home/user145/public_html/sistema/application/controllers/Dashboard.php
>   Line: 7
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/user145/public_html/sistema/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Após subir ao servidor, algumas páginas não estão sendo encontradas quando tento acessar.

Comment: Coloque o local do erro, os códigos referentes!

Comment: primeiro erro alguma $query tua que esta retornando uma int que não pode ser resolvido.

O segundo, essa exception é a codificação que tem que ser utf-8, mas tudo isso pode ser expeculação já que não contem um exemplo minimo verificavel, post seu codigo

Comment: ok, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: `if ($resultados) { .....` já assim resolve!

Comment: Agradeço. mas isso não é normal... no localhost fucniona e subo no servidor, não funciona

Comment: @user102074 é dificil dizer se realmente no `localhost` está funcionando corretamente, porque, não temos como testar, agora eu indiquei o código errado que você está fazendo, porque, ali não retorna um inteiro, ali pode retornar `null` ou um `objeto` por isso eu disse tire `>0`! então você está programando errado, não me leve tão pouco mau ... é um indicação que falta estudar mais um pouquinho.

Comment: O erro foi corrigido, mas porque agora não funciona meu ajax? não encontra nenhuma página? é como se os links estivessem obsoletos

Comment: @user102074 ai é outro contexto, com certeza o teu código tem outros problemas!

Comment: as minhs views não estão sendo encotnradas

Comment: @user102074 estranho mesmo, então, tem mais problemas de codificação.

Comment: `Operation not permitted` Provavelmente o seu `PHP` não tem permissão para escrita/remoção desse arquivo de sessão. Cheque as permissões. Há algum erro quando você tenta acessar suas `views`? Você está utilizando as mesmas configs (Apache/Nginx, PHP etc) do localhost no servidor??

Comment: Quando eu tento acessar as views, ocorre o erro 404 no network do navegador. As views estão no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Como os comentários apontaram acima, talvez falta um pouco de experiência na programação. Na linha 12 você esta verificando se a consulta retornou algum dado. Para fazer isso não é necessário fazer ´$resultados > 0`, visto que, em php, tudo é considerado verdadeiro, exceto

1. 0 (zero numério)
2. "0" (zero string)
3. false
4. "" (string vazia)
5. null
6. array() (array vazio)

Caso queira estudar um pouco mais sobre isso sugiro a própria documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php)

Logo, para fazer essa comparação basta fazer

```
if ($resultados)
```

Revise todo o seu código para verificar se isso não está acontecendo em outros lugares.

Comment: eu agradeço a ajuda. mas o problema agora é outro

Comment: eu postei os outros erros que acontecem. Minhas views não estão sendo encontradas. estou usando ` base_url()` nos links e alterei o arquivo `config.php`.

Comment: que valor vc colocar pra sua url base?

Comment: eu coloco o link onde está o sistema exemplo: `http://meusite.com.br/sistema/`... assim desse jeito

Comment: no seu servidor, você colocou seu sistema todo dentro de uma pasta chamado sistema? pq caso contrário não tem necessidade dessa parte. Seria muito mais fácil achar os erro se vc postasse o link do seu site. Isso é possível?

Comment: isso, dentro de uma pasta.. pq isso é uma má pratica? eu nao posso colocar na raiz... na raiz tem um site.

Comment: Pode ser assim, sem problemas. Tente ver o que está acontecendo na aba network do seu navegador

Comment: o fato de estar numa pasta, impede que minhas views sejam encontradas?

Comment: Não. Eu já subi sistemas que estavam em subpastas do sistema e tudo funcionou normalmente. Sem mais informações (código) não vai ter como te ajudar a achar o problema.

Comment: Quando eu tento acessar as views, ocorre o erro 404 no network do navegador. As views estão no servidor.